# Function "move_by_offset(x, y)" only works in the first time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the following code to write multiple dots on the paper.

But the result paper only has 1 dot.

The error message was

```
elenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds.
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://kleki.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
x,y=map(int,input().split())
for i in range(3):
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_by_offset(x, y-i*100)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
    time.sleep(7)
```

By the way,[Python Selenium `move_by_offset` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433411/python-selenium-move-by-offset-doesnt-work) didn't help me.

How do I implement it?.

Comment: What are the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: It represents the initial position of the dot.

Comment: I asked what are the values? x = 50 y = 20?

Comment: I assume it with (600,600).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point is in location (600, 600). In the second iteration you don't move the mouse to point (600, 500), you are moving it to point (1200, 1100) which is outside the browser boundaries.

One solution is to set `x` and `y` to 0 after the first `move_by_offset()`

```
action.move_by_offset(x, y - i * 100)
x, y = 0, 0
```

You can also select the movement base on the html size to make sure it's always in boundaries

```
x, y = map(int, '600 600'.split())
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
width = body.size['width']
height = body.size['height']
for i in range(3):
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_by_offset(x, y - i * 100)
    x = int((width - x) / 10)
    y = int((height - y) / 10)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
```